# Find most frequent terms in a text field in an index

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to find the list of terms in a `text` field which are most frequently indexed. This list would contain elements in reverse sorted order of their `term.docFreq` values. I have been looking into [terms vector API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-termvectors.html) but you have to know the term beforehand. Is there any other API provided by elasticsearch which provides the list in reverse sorted order of `term.docFreq` values?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, your solution might be this:

1. you must set "fielddata": true" in the mapping of your field.
2. you use terms aggregation as below to find your answer:

   ```
    GET index_name/_search 
    {
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "your_field_name",
            "order": { "_count": "asc" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
   ```

by this query, you will have the words with a lower frequency to higher. if you omit the order part in the query you will have the result in desc order.